# Query best possible matches and order them

Tags: query, ms-access, order-by

I'm trying to write a query along these lines:

```
select * 
from tbl 
where 
       col1 = 1 
   and col2 = 2 
   and col3 = 3
order by
   ...
;
```

I want first all the results where all 3 `WHERE` conditions match (3/3), then all the results where any 2 conditions match (2/3), and finally the results where any 1 condition matches (1/3).

Each of these 3 result sets needs to be ordered by `(col4, col5, col6)`.

Can I do that in a single query?

For example:

[sample http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/1646/sampletableresult1.jpg](http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/1646/sampletableresult1.jpg)

Script to create test data:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MyTable]') AND type in (N'U'))
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
    col1 INT
    , col2 INT 
    , col3 INT 
    , col4 INT 
    , col5 INT 
    , col6 INT 
)
GO

INSERT dbo.MyTable (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)
SELECT 1,2,3,2,1,1 UNION ALL 
SELECT 1,2,30,1,1,1 UNION ALL SELECT 1,20,30,1,1,1 UNION ALL 
SELECT 10,20,3,1,1,1 UNION ALL SELECT 10,2,30,1,1,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 10,2,3,1,1,1 UNION ALL SELECT 10,20,30,1,1,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2,3,1,1,1 UNION ALL SELECT 1,2,3,1,2,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2,3,1,2,3 UNION ALL SELECT 1,20,3,1,1,1
GO
```

Comment: if possible without 3! join
the sample have 3 first col, but in reality, its more than that

Comment: So you want to find all rows where all 3 conditions match, then where any 2 conditions match, then where any 1 condition matches and put all the results together, sorted by col4, 5, and 6.  Is that correct?

Comment: yeah, I know, I was searching another way, because its more than 3 col

Comment: [select * from tbl where col1 and col2 and col3 order by col4,col5,col6]
[select * from tbl where col1 and col2]
[select * from tbl where col2 and col3]
[select * from tbl where col1 and col3]
[select * from tbl where col1]
[select * from tbl where col2]
[select * from tbl where col3]

Comment: Is this SQL Server?

Comment: well, for the moment its access (I'm waiting to get my sql server db)

Comment: If you'll eventually be using SQL Server, install the [express edition](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23650). Clean upgrade path to a paid for version and no dealing with syntax idiosyncrasies in Access.

Comment: I know, I wait for 1, but bureaucracy made it so much hard at my job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT col1, 
       col2,
       col3, 
       col4, 
       col5, 
       col6
FROM TableX 
WHERE col1 = 1 
   OR col2 = 2 
   OR col3 = 3 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN col1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
         (CASE WHEN col2 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
         (CASE WHEN col3 = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC,
         col4, col5, col6
```

or, for MS-Access:

```
ORDER BY IIF(col1 = 1,1,0) +
         IIF(col2 = 2,1,0) +
         IIF(col3 = 3,1,0) DESC,
         col4, col5, col6
```

Comment: @Mark: What combinations you mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: @ypercube I concede, +1 :)

Comment: @Mark: thnx, I was starting to worry that I hadn't understood the question.

Comment: seems good, but I'm stock now with access db, and I try this, and I dont get the good result (SELECT col1, 
       col2,
       col3, 
       col4, 
       col5, 
       col6
FROM mytable
WHERE col1 = 1 
   OR col2 = 2 
   OR col3 = 3 
ORDER BY IIF(col1 = 1,1,0) +IIF(col2 = 1,1,0) +IIF(col3 = 1,1,0) desc,col4,col5,col6)

Comment: Small modification: `IIF(col1 = 1,1,0) +IIF(col2 = 2,1,0) +IIF(col3 = 3,1,0) desc`

Comment: mistake on the query but still wrong SELECT col1, 
       col2,
       col3, 
       col4, 
       col5, 
       col6,
       IIF(col1 = 1,5,0),
IIF(col2 = 1,3,0),
IIF(col3 = 1,1,0)
FROM mytable
WHERE col1 = 1 
   OR col2 = 2 
   OR col3 = 3 
ORDER BY IIF(col1 = 1,1,0) +IIF(col2 = 2,1,0) +IIF(col3 = 3,1,0) desc,col4,col5,col6

Comment: just need to add 3 first col after case ( DESC , mytable.col1, mytable.col2, mytable.col3)

Comment: tank you guys !!

Comment: I couldn't get the "Case" statement and it's necessity in order by . Can anybody make it a little bit clear please?

Comment: @Pantea the question asks for: *"I want first all the results where all 3 WHERE conditions match (3/3), then all the results where any 2 conditions match (2/3), and finally the results where any 1 condition matches (1/3)."* The three CASE expressions check each condition and give 1 or 0. When added the result is 3, 2 or 1, depending on how many conditions match. Then we order in DESCending order to get the rows that 3 conditions match first, then 2, then 1.

Answer (score 1):

Would this achieve what you want?  Technicly the inline view isnt necessary as you could repeat the case statement in the order by.

```
select y.col1, 
       y.col2,
       y.col3, 
       y.col4, 
       y.col5, 
       y.col6
from (
      select col1, 
             col2, 
             col3, 
             case when col1 =1 and col2 = 2 and col3 = 3 then
                       1
                  when col1 = 1 and col2 = 2 and col3 <> 3 then
                       2
                  when col1 = 1 then
                       3
                  else 
                       4
             end x,
             col4, 
             col5, 
             col6
       from table
       )y
order by y.x, col4, col5, col6
```

Comment: What if col1 and col3 match?  Or just col2?  The OP is looking for all 3 match, *any two* match, *any one* matches.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       col4,
       col5,
       col6
FROM TableName
WHERE col1 = 1
   OR col2 = 2
   OR col3 = 3
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN col1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC,
         (CASE WHEN col2 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC,
         (CASE WHEN col3 = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC,
         col4, col5, col6
```

Comment: No, this query will order the row with `(col1,col2,col3)` = `(1,0,0)` (1 match) before the row with `(0,2,3)` (2 matches).